# CSS selection HTML conditional css

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to select a CSS based on one particular 'id' used in the page.

For example.

HTML

```
<li id="button_preview" href="#inline_content2"></li> 

<li id="button_suspend" href="#inline_content1"></li>
```

Here I need to select one style sheet for `#inline_content1` and another stylesheet for `#inline_content2`. Is it possible to do?

Comment: If both stylesheets are linked in your document, and one of them has the style for `#button_preview` and the other one has the style for `#button_suspend` then what's your problem?

Comment: Could it be the question means that the result (after jumping) has to be styled differently, according to which link was clicked? I.E. a different stylesheet for `page.html#inline_content1` than for `page.htmll#inline_content2`?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, [ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors).

```
li#button_preview {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a specific style-*sheet* based on the attribute-value, or `id`, of an element, but you can apply a particular *style* to an element based on its attribute value:

```
li[href='#inline_content1'] {
    /* css */
}

li[href='#inline_content2'] {
    /* css */
}
```

Or, to use the `id`:

```
#inline_content1 {
    /* css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css like this:

```
#button_preview {

}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp